# Scanner variable not found

Tags: java

I actually just started Java...

**I am getting an error as :**

```
Bank.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
           sc.nextInt();
           ^
 symbol:   variable sc
  location: class Bank
1 error
```

**and my code is** :

```
import java.util.*;
public  class Bank
{

    public  static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome To The Bank Portal");
        System.out.println("1-----Deposit Money\n2-----Withdrawal\n3-----Show Balance\n4----Transfer Money\n5-----Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Choice: ");
        int a=sc.nextInt();

        switch(a)
        {
            case 1: Bank ac;

        }
    }

    public static void ac()
    {
        System.out.println("1-----A/C 123321\n2-----A/C 987789");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Choice: ");
        sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: `sc` is a local variable of the main method. So it's only usable inside the main method. Unless you pass it as argument to ac()

Answer (score 3):

`sc` is not in scope in the `ac` method. It's declared in the `main` method, so it's only in scope in the `main` method.

To make it available in the `ac` method, pass it as a parameter:

```
public static void ac(Scanner sc)
```

And to call it (e.g. in `main`)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // this you already have
...
ac(sc);
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the `ac` method is never called, and `Bank ac` in that `switch` statement does nothing.

Comment: ac void is for displaying account information...Is there any way to use sc as a globally declared...

Comment: Yes, but it's not a good idea. You *could* declare it as `static Scanner sc` outside of `main` (just inside the class), then inside `main` you can do `sc = new Scanner(System.in)` (notice, not `Scanner sc = `' just `sc = `). But again, you shouldn't do it.